# C++ Chrono 32/64 bits + Release/Debug

Tags: c++, x86-64, c++-chrono

I am having trouble with the  in c++ visual studio 2015

Consider this version:

```
#ifndef CHRONO_INFO_H
#define CHRONO_INFO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

class c_ChronoInfo
{
private:
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _start;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _stop;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _totaltime;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _laptime;
    bool _isPaused;

    const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _zeroDuration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::zero();

public:
    c_ChronoInfo() :
        _totaltime(_zeroDuration),
        _isPaused(true)
    {
    }

    ~c_ChronoInfo() {}

    void Start()
    {
        assert(_isPaused);
        _isPaused = false;
        _start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        assert(!_isPaused);
        _stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        _laptime = _stop - _start;
        _totaltime += _laptime;
        _isPaused = true;
    }

private:
    inline auto _totalChronosI() const
    {
        return _totaltime;
    }

public:
    inline double TotalMilliseconds() const { return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>>(_totalChronosI()).count(); }

};

#endif // CHRONO_INFO_H
```

When I compile in 64 bits and release mode, very short times are outputted as expected say using:

```
c_ChronoInfo test;
test.Start();
int x = 0;
for (long long i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
{
    x = i;
}
test.Stop();
std::cout << "test: " << test.TotalMilliseconds() << std::endl;
```

but when I compile in 32 bits or Debug (32 or 64), I get negative or very big times.

Furthermore, the _laptime variable is defined in the class but is not really needed.  However, if it is defined as needed in the methods, i.e.,

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _laptime = _stop - _start;
```

The code behaves again completely unexpected even in 64 bits/ release mode.

Thanks

Comment: it's an example.  In fact, you don't even need the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_zeroDuration` in non-static and non-constexpr and is not initialized yet at the time you use it to initialize `_totaltime` in the constructor initialization list because it's declared later in the class.

So it happens that the memory contains a value that is later looks like a big negative floating-point number.

To fix the initialization order you can either move the declaration of `_zeroDuration` before the one of `_totaltime`

```
// first
const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _zeroDuration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::zero();
...
// second
std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _laptime;
bool _isPaused;
...
c_ChronoInfo() :
    _totaltime(_zeroDuration),
    _isPaused(true)
```

or initialize the `_totaltime` directly like:

```
c_ChronoInfo() :
    _totaltime(std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::zero()),
```

or make `_zeroDuration` a `constexpr`:

```
static constexpr std::chrono::steady_clock::duration _zeroDuration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::zero();
```

You also better initialize all variables of 'std::chrono::duration' type because they have defaulted constexpr constructors and are not zero-initialized.

---

You do not need `duration_cast` in `TotalMilliseconds`:

```
inline double TotalMilliseconds() const {
    return std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(_totalChronosI()).count();
}
```

Comment: It's possible they also expected `_zeroduration` to be static, which would mean it would get initialized before the constructor ran.  But it isn't, so there's a new one of those for each class instance... I think.

Comment: Static in-class initialization would not work, will need an extra cpp file. And `duration` has a `constexpr` constructor so `static constexpr` works.

Comment: @A.A  Thanks.  I opted for static constexpr.  I need the duration_cast in the actual more generic version of my class.

Answer (score 2):

Your class has field initialization reordering problem `_zeroDuration` is always initialized after `_totaltime` because they are declared in such order so after calling `_totaltime(_zeroDuration)` `_totaltime` is still filled with garbage. To fix it just throw away `_zeroDuration`:

```
c_ChronoInfo() :
    _totaltime(std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::zero())
```